# Can I change a Vuex store state for a layout from a component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am using Nuxt with vuetify.

Vuetify helpfully creates a drawer in the default layout (Pretty cool)

I would like to use a Vuex store to change the state of the drawer contained within the default layout from within a page or component.

I have the following in my store index.js

```
const createStore = () => {
return new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
   //Default State
    showDrawer:false,
  },
   
});
  };

   export default createStore
```

In my default layout I have

```
<v-navigation-drawer 
      v-if="$showDrawer.state.show"
```

Calling that directly works as expected, but is it possible from within a page to mutate the showDrawer state to true?

If so how, assuming its a mutation and committing the change through an action from what I have read but new to Vuex and would very much appreciate some guidance. I am sure there are better ways to solve this but keen to learn how to do this using Vuex if someone is able to offer an example.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, in the page I add

```
beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.commit('UPDATE_DRAWER', false);
}
```

And as a mutation I add

```
mutations: {
        UPDATE_DRAWER(state, payload) {
            state.show = payload
        }
       },
```

Thanks for looking, am sure I may be getting something slightly wrong still so feel free to let me know if what I am doing is incorrect, all helps with my learning :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with this approach and there is no better way of solving this one. Keeping things simple is usually great!